# When documentation's Usage merely says `> fooBar` what does that mean?

Tags: scala, sbt

Yes, a beginner question!  I'm looking at https://github.com/sbt/sbt-license-report and see the usage section of:

```
 > dumpLicenseReport

This dumps a ...
```

Well no, that is a partial application of the greater-than operator, `>`.  But seriously, I think this means:

One: Run `sbt`

```
$ sbt
... debug info ...
[proj-name] $
```

OK, we're in a sort of REPL. Now two: `dumpLicenseReport`:

```
[proj-name] $ dumpLicenseReport
[error] dumpLicenseReport
[error]                  ^
```

Ok so that wasn't a repl so much as an "sbt shell".  In this shell one valid command is `console` which does get to a repl:

```
[proj-name] $ console
...
scala> dumpLicenseReport
       ^
       error: not found: value dumpLicenseReport
```

OOps, I didn't define the license.sbt file they show in the instructions. Doing that then...

```
[proj-name] $ console
...
scala> dumpLicenseReport
...
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last update for the full output
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-license-report;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.13:1.2.0
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: .../.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-license-report/scala_2.13/sbt_1.0/1.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-license-report_2.13_1.0/1.2.0/sbt-license-report-1.2.0.pom
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-license-report_2.13_1.0/1.2.0/sbt-license-report-1.2.0.pom
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Feb 5, 2021, 10:18:25 PM
```

Now I'm guessing I just need to enter the right upstream location somewhere but I've not used sbt before.  Would someone show me how to go from a *nix system with bash + sbt + jdk11 to running sbt-license-report?

Comment: That seems to be a sbt command as you first attempted, Did you installed it before trying to run it?

Comment: How do you install a license script?  Perhaps `sbt` then `compile`?  I did compile it... ohh, but not after I placed the `license.sbt` under the `project` subdirectory (I had previously had it top level, which is clearly not what the readme says).  I think it it working now, thank you. I would have played around forever with the console.

Comment: Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez indicated this is an SBT command intended to be ran from an SBT shell so the process is:

1. Enter your repository directory
2. Ensure you created license.sbt correctly, including having it under the `project` sub directory.
3. run `sbt compile`
4. run `sbt dumpLicenseReport`

Or Instead of steps 3 and 4 you can enter the shell with just `sbt` and execute commands of `compile` then `dumpLicenseReport`.  The `>` prompt in the readme of the sbt-license-report repository indicates an SBT shell and not a repl (the "console") and certainly not a naked *nix shell (bash, zsh, etc).